Bifurcation Diagram based on unknown function
I am new to this knowledge. Here is the given scenario of the problem (please check the picture for clarification). Given a function $u'(t) = f(u;m)$, $t$ is time, $u$ is the enzyme concentration at time $t$,  $m$ is the parameter. We know that when $m = 25$, the stable points are $1.0$ and $2.0$; when $m = 50$, the stable point is $1.3$. Based on this info, can we know how to draw a bifurcation diagram?
Here is the plot recording the time course of the concentration $u$ for various initial conditions:

And the final question is: suppose at time $0$, the
concentration of our enzyme $u(0)$ was $0.8 \, \mathrm{mM}$. Assuming $m = 40 \, \mathrm{mg}$ is fixed, what is the
approximate value of $u(10,000)$?
I am a bit confused. Thank you for your help!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can't construct a bifurcation diagram from just knowing what happens at two discrete values of a parameter.

At m=50 we have only one stable fixed point and at m=25 we have 3 fixed points: 2 stable fixed points and 1 unstable fixed point.
A similar example is
$$ x' = -x^4 - ax^2 $$
At $a=0$ we have only one stable fixed point at $x=0$ (similar to $m=50$ in your example), and at $a<0$ we have 3 fixed points: $x=0$, $x=-\sqrt{a}$, and $x=\sqrt{a}$.
You can play on this website
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4scfpu5qbi
With this idea, we can assume that your function is
$$x^4 + \frac{m-50}{100}x^4 $$.
We can see that in $m=25$ the difference between your fixed point is $0.5$ and $\sqrt{m}=0.5 \Rightarrow m = 0.25$.
With this idea you can calculate the fixed point at $m=40$ where $x(t)$ converges to the initial point $x(0) = 0.8$.
It is not very rigorous, but I hope it is useful to you.
